# Tarea Programada Java

Tags: java

Necesito ejecutar una tarea el primer día de cada mes `(1/11 , 1/12, 1/01)`, estos parámetros los obtengo desde una base de datos por lo que no puedo utilizar la anotación `@Schedule()`, por lo que necesito configurarlo mediante variables `String o Integer`

```
TpParametro parametro = parametrosRepo.getParametroTime();  
String[] valor = parametro.getValor().split(" ");     
String segundos= valor[0];   
String minutos= valor[1];   
String horas = valor[2];  
String dia = valor[3];  
String mes = valor[4];
```

Comment: La pregunta es porque no usas Schedule()??  si se puede consultar a la base de datos y hacer un insert, update.

Comment: Ejemplo: @Schedule(dayOfWeek="Sun", hour="0") cuando es anotación no puedo asignar variables a los parámetros de entrada

Comment: Claro que si se puede, si editas la pregunta y pones código y explicas mas con gusto puedo poner un ejemplo

Comment: Listo así obtengo los parámetros de la bbdd

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es declarar los `String` como constantes así:

```
public static final String segundos= "";
public static final String minutos= "";
public static final String horas = "";
public static final String dia = "";
public static final String mes = "";
```

Luego con la anotación `@PostConstruct` que lo que hace es después de pasar por el constructor llama la función que tenga debajo de la a llenar estas variables de esta manera:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
TpParametro parametro = parametrosRepo.getParametroTime();
String[] valor = parametro.getValor().split(" ");
segundos= valor[0];
minutos= valor[1];
horas = valor[2];
dia = valor[3];
mes = valor[4];
}
```

Teniendo esto ya puede usar `@Schedule` con tus parámetros.

```
@Schedule(second = segundos, minute = minutos, hour =horas, dayOfWeek =dia, month =mes)
public void tuFuncion() {
return null;
}
```

Comment: "The final field PeriodicTimer.segundos cannot be assigned" no puedo reasignar valores a las variables debido a que son "final "

Comment: y no las tienes en la base de datos ahí deberías cambiar los valores

Comment: Estoy obteniendo los parámetros desde un repositorio con java JPA, al traerme los valores me traigo un string con espacios y despues separo los valores

Comment: Deberías de usar trim en la consulta para no hacer nada con el String